# iOS zoom in WebView containing local HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview, zooming

I have a WebView with local HTML and JavaScript made by animate CC, but it's impossible to zoom in my pages.

I activated "Scale Page to Fit", but nothing works.

Do I have to do something special in Animate CC, or modify my HTML or JavaScript?

Maybe in my `webview.m`?

Here's my `.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<title>accueil</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<style>
  #canvas {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;right:0;
    top:0;bottom:0;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="accueil.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    handleComplete();
}
function handleComplete() {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    exportRoot = new lib.accueil();
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot); 
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);        
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    (function(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType) {        
        var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;      
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);        
        resizeCanvas();     
        function resizeCanvas() {           
            var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;            
            var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;          
            var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;           
            if(isResp) {                
                if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
                    sRatio = lastS;                
                }               
                else if(!isScale) {                 
                    if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
                        sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }               
                else if(scaleType==1) {                 
                    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }               
                else if(scaleType==2) {                 
                    sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }           
            }           
            canvas.width = w*pRatio*sRatio;         
            canvas.height = h*pRatio*sRatio;
            canvas.style.width = w*sRatio+'px';         
            canvas.style.height = h*sRatio+'px';
            stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;           
            stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;           
            lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;     
        }
    })(true,'both',true,1); 
}
</script>
<!-- write your code here -->
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="657" height="1202" style="display: block; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00)"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/animate/using/working-with-camera-in-animate-cc.html links within that talk about camera zooming

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).